# Iris data set split function not compiling?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I am attempting to randomly split 2 data sets (numpy arrays) using the train_test_split function but for some reason my code is not compiling.

```
# Iris data set, hello world of Machine Learning
#classes: possible outcomes
#label: for each data point, its classification
# this is a three class classification problem

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test,y_train y_test = train_test_split(iris_dataset['data'], 
iris_dataset['target'],random_state=0)
```

error message:

```
runfile('C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-63-5ba32625e270>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 35
    X_train, X_test,y_train y_test = train_test_split(iris_dataset['data'], iris_dataset['target'])
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

runfile('C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-64-5ba32625e270>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 35
    X_train, X_test,y_train y_test = train_test_split(iris_dataset['data'], iris_dataset['target'],random_state=0)
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a comma between `y_train` & `y_test` in line:

```
X_train, X_test,y_train y_test = train_test_split(iris_dataset['data'], 
iris_dataset['target'],random_state=0)
```

Comment: @Petrarca Am glad it helped. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers